# SQL Blocking, SPID of -2

Tags: sql-server

We have some blocking going on in our database and when I run sp_who2, in the BlkBy field, I see "-2" for two of the rows.  What does this mean?  Running SQL Server 2008 R2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see "-2" for two of the rows. What does this mean?

[It means you have an open DTC transaction managed by an external ITransaction interface but no Sessions currently using it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-orphan-dtc-transaction-sessionspid-2)

you have to use `KILL UOW` where UOW = UnitOfWork associated with that transaction instead of the session id.

---- in text mode run below query

```
select 'kill ' , req_transactionUOW
from master..syslockinfo
where req_spid = -2
```

Comment: I am not sure why the individual just deleted the answer but according to Paul Randal's post: [SPID -2 is an orphaned DTC transaction](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-dealing-with-negative-spids-2-and-3/)

Comment: @ShawnMelton If you look at the [CSS post by Bob Dorr](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/04/20/how-it-works-orphan-dtc-transaction-session-spid-2.aspx), he explains why it is not called Orphan. Especially `A -2 is not Orphaned it means there are NO ENLISTED SESSIONS on the SQL Server but the transaction is active yet.`

Comment: Thanks for re-posting the link to Paul Randal's post.  Kin's suggested solution worked for me. Thanks

Comment: NO ENLISTED SESSIONS, or a transaction that is no longer tied to a session (orphaned)...just terminology to me. It is just as easy to explain it as being orphaned.